# My php code suddenly can't work in javascript code

Tags: javascript, php

This is my code.

[image]

I don't know why it suddenly can't work today.
As you see in the image the is light-blue,
it should be dark-blue in visual stuido code.

Does anyone having the same issue?

Comment: Maybe you mean `alert(<?php echo 1; ?>);`

Comment: Umm, may i just cap a screen shot is better

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have listed your problem, but to understand you we need to know the expected output. Please include it in the question.

Comment: k i updated an image.

Comment: Do you have an error ?

Comment: Please see the image

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code...

Comment: you can see that the <script> </script> is different color, it should be same i dun know why it suddenly like this :(

Comment: what do you mean "out of order"? what is your expected outcome?

Comment: maybe you have a disabled alert/pop up messages from the browser? can you see the rendered HTML code?

Comment: What IDE are you using? Looks like an IDE failing to understand the two languages mixed up, rather than a coding issue.

Comment: im using Visual Studio Code

Comment: @K2R yes you are right. I got the same issue in my VS code IDE. seems a bug. but not related to PHP or javascript.

Comment: @Oshanz K, thanks.

Comment: Your code should work i tried it on my localhost. The problem is somewhere else but not in the code.

Answer (score -2):

You can try like below.

```
<?php
    echo "a";
?>
<script>
    alert(1);
    function test()
    {
        alert("<?php echo 1; ?>");
    }
    test();
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why this should answer op question ?

Comment: Sorry executable. Its not a op question.
Its working

Comment: @Ramya it's an OP Question. He didn't state his expected output. His code is working fine but we don't know whaw he actually wants to achieve

Comment: @Ramya OP (op) = Original Poster i.e. the person who asked the question.

Comment: Got it. Thanks Nick and Kanayo.